# WP 8.1 Silverlight : How to update a Line (coordinate change)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on an OCR project and part of it is finding the outlines of an object. To debug it, I output lines on the screen of the phone (to represent the outlines) with the [`<Line />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.line) Xaml element. I'm trying to update the Line each time I find a different outline. The lines show the good result on the first "frame" but then don't move anymore. (The thing that I change are their X1,Y1 and X2,Y2 attributes).
For a Line1 element :

XAML of the element :

```
<Line x:Name="Line1"
      Stroke="Yellow" />
```

C# that changes the coordinates :

```
Line1.X1 = some_new_value;
Line1.Y1 = some_new_value2;
Line1.X2 = some_new_value3;
Line1.Y2 = some_new_value4;
```

This is the C# I have tried to update the line :

```
Line1.InvalidateArrange();
Line1.InvalidateMeasure();
```

(separatly and together but it doesn't change anything)

What is the good way of doing this? Or perhaps I shouldn't be using `<Line />` and there is a better way to do this, in which case what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Binding through a ViewModel or you can call UpdateLayout for the control or the page itself.

```
this.UpdateLayout();
```

Or

```
Line1.UpdateLayout();
```